# Multi Firestore database

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a mobile app , and this mobile app works currently with one google fire store database.

I want to see this app to more than one customer and I don't want to make a collection for each customer.

Instead I want to open a new database.

I know that I need to import the JSON file for each database.

**My Question:**

Can I tell the app to use database one then if you login with another
account use database 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update (late 2023)**: You can now have multiple Firestore databases per project. See the blog post [Manage multiple Firestore databases in a project](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/manage-multiple-firestore-databases-in-a-project), my [announcement video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTjLidwxsm0#t=54s), and the documentation on [managing databases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-databases).

---

Previous answer

There is only a single Firestore database instance per Firebase project. There is (currently) no way to add additional Firestore database instances to a project.

So that means you'd have to have a separate project for each user. That part is technically feasible for databases, as you can dynamically [create a `FirebaseApp` instance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.html#initializeApp(android.content.Context,%20com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions)) with the [configuration data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.html) for the signed in user. The problem is that you need to first sign in the user (which requires that you already have a `FirebaseApp` instance for the project that this user is registered on.

I'd highly recommend reconsidering **why** you want to create a separate Firestore instance for each user, as creating user-specific sub-collections is by far the simplest way to implement a multi-user application on Firestore.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Frank-van-puffelen how many of these answers do you need to update now that Firestore has MultiDB support :-) ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTjLidwxsm0#t=54s (that's you live with the announcement, cheers)

Comment: Oof... thanks for flagging Mike. There's quite a few, but not nearly as much as on OR queries. :(

Answer (score 0):

it's now possible to create multiple databases in Firestore.

See [Manage multiple Firestore databases in a project](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/manage-multiple-firestore-databases-in-a-project)

```bash
gcloud firestore databases create --database=test --location=us-west1 --type=firestore-native
```